# Unable to get Post data from Android

Tags: php, post

I create a file which accept parameters using post method, android service is going to pass parameter to this file. I tested the file with POSTMAN it works fine but at the time of live testing POST variables get emptied. Here is url of my service created in php.
https://mygk.eschoolportals.com/mygk/modules/subjectcat/user_quize_score_ins.php

Here is code snipest

```
<?php 
require '../../include/config.php';
if(strtoupper($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) == 'POST')
{
    $appuserid = $_REQUEST['tid'];
    $score = 0;
    $time = date('h:i:s');
    $date = date('Y-m-d');
    $correctans = $_REQUEST['correct'];
    $totalqns = $_REQUEST['size'];
    $correct = $_REQUEST['correctquestionid'];
    $incorrect = $_REQUEST['incorrectquestionid'];
    $correct_array = explode(',',$correct);
    $incorrect_array = explode(',',$incorrect);
    $wishlistid = '0';
    $incorrectans = $totalqns-$correctans;
    if($totalqns!='')
    {
    $score = round($correctans/$totalqns*100,2);
    $totalpoints = round($totalqns/$totalqns*100,2); 
    }
    $qryselchk = $m->executeSelectQuery("SELECT * FROM `tbl_user_score` WHERE `userid`='$userid' AND `subjectid`='$subjectid' 
        AND `categoryid`='$sub_categoryid' AND `sub_sub_categoryid`='$sub_sub_categoryid'");
    if(mysqli_num_rows($qryselchk)>=1)
    {
    $qryins = $m->executeQuery("UPDATE `tbl_user_score` SET `time`='$time',`date`='$date',`correctans`='$correctans',`incorrectans`='$incorrectans',`score`='$score' WHERE `userid`='$userid' AND `subjectid`='$subjectid' AND `categoryid`='$sub_categoryid' AND `sub_sub_categoryid`='$sub_sub_categoryid'");

    $qryremove = $m->executeQuery("DELETE FROM `tbl_user_quize_report` WHERE `quizeid`='$sub_sub_categoryid'");
    foreach ($correct_array as $C) {
    $qryins_correct = $m->executeQuery("INSERT INTO `tbl_user_quize_report`(`qnid`,`quizeid`,`userquizid`,`userid`,`answerflag`
    ,`last_date_added`) VALUES ('$C','$sub_sub_categoryid','0','$userid','1',NOW())");
    }
    foreach ($incorrect_array as $I) {
    $qryins_incorrect = $m->executeQuery("INSERT INTO `tbl_user_quize_report`(`qnid`,`quizeid`,`userquizid`,`userid`,`answerflag`
    ,`last_date_added`) VALUES ('$I','$sub_sub_categoryid','$wishlistid','$userid','0',NOW())");
    }

    }
    else
    {
    $qryins = $m->executeQuery("INSERT INTO `tbl_user_score`(`userid`,`subjectid`,`time`,`date`,`correctans`,`incorrectans`,`score`,`categoryid`,`sub_sub_categoryid`) 
        VALUES ('$userid','$subjectid','$time','$date','$correctans','$incorrectans','$score','$sub_categoryid','$sub_sub_categoryid')");   
    foreach ($correct_array as $C) {
    $qryins_correct = $m->executeQuery("INSERT INTO `tbl_user_quize_report`(`qnid`,`quizeid`,`userquizid`,`userid`,`answerflag`
    ,`last_date_added`) VALUES ('$C','$sub_sub_categoryid','$wishlistid','$userid','1',NOW())");
    }
    foreach ($incorrect_array as $I) {
    $qryins_incorrect = $m->executeQuery("INSERT INTO `tbl_user_quize_report`(`qnid`,`quizeid`,`userquizid`,`userid`,`answerflag`
    ,`last_date_added`) VALUES ('$I','$sub_sub_categoryid','$wishlistid','$userid','0',NOW())");
    }

    }
    if($qryins)
    {
        $response["Score"] = array();
        {
            $rows = array();
            $rows["UserId"] = $appuserid;
            $rows["nameid"] = $subjectname;
            $rows["Correct"] = (int)$correctans;
            $rows["totalpoints"] = $totalpoints;
            $rows["score"] = $score;
            $rows["Size"] = (int)$totalqns;
            array_push($response["Score"], $rows);
        }
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Error!".mysqli_error($m->con);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: First of all, please visit http://bobby-tables.com and learn about SQL injection. Your code is not safe at all andf your whole database could be deleted in a few seconds. Always use prepared statements when it comes to query the database with user inputs. Also, I don't see any definition of `$userid` in the first query. Shouldn't that one be the `$appuserid` ?

Comment: its right since  $userid = $m->getUserid($appuserid);   ..  i face post data get emptied whenever posted to php script

Comment: I don't see the `$userid = $m->getUserid()` anywhere in your code. And as long as there are no prepared statements in your code, I refuse to help you. Would be awesome if you change all your statements like in the examples given on the mentioned website and post your edited code again here.

Comment: you did'nt get my actual problem anyway no problem!

Comment: Above problem has been resolved! Thank You!